# How do I check if files in my folder coincide with the file names specified in my .csv file?

Tags: python, csv, file

I am trying to build a method that will check if the file names in my .csv file will match the file names in my actual file folder. If they don't match, I want to delete the whole row of on my .csv file. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
dir_path = Path('D:\audio_files')
    
csv_file_path = Path('D:\metadata.csv') 

lines = list()
files = list()

for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    f = f.strip('.wav')
    files.append(str(f))

with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file)
    for row in reader:
        lines.append(row)
        for field in row:
            for f in files:
                if field != f:
                    print("Line Removed.")
                    lines.remove(row)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file_checker.py", line 26, in <module>
lines.remove(row)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

What is it I should fix to get it to work?

**EDIT :**

Here is a small sample of my .csv file. It's very straight forward. First column contains file names without the extension, and second column contains the labels of the filenames.

| fname | label |
| --- | --- |
| 236421 | Male_speech |
| 124818 | Female_speech |
| 426906 | Male_speech |

And so on.

I am basically trying to match the names in the *fname* column to the ones in my file folder (with extension *.wav*) and if the names do not exist in the file folder, the delete the row of the non-existent file name.

**EDIT #2 :**

I managed to solve the problem with a bit of local help. Here is the final product:

```
dir_path = 'D:\audio'

csv_file_path = 'D:\original.csv'

#create a new file that contains the fnames on the cvs file that match the file names in my file folder
csv_new_file = open('D:\new.csv', 'w', newline="")

# create a writer variable that will allow me to write rows in my new csv file
csv_write = csv.writer(csv_new_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

# "i" variable will allow me to write the headers from the original csv file
i = 0
with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
#If the row is the very first, the write it as is (headers)
        if i == 0:
            csv_write.writerow(row)  
            i += 1
            continue
#Check if the file path for my audio files with .wav extension exists and the write the row of the original csv in my new csv
        file_path = dir_path + '/' + row[0] + '.wav'
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            csv_write.writerow(row)

#IMPORTANT to close files once finished!
csv_new_file.close()
read_file.close()
```

Comment: The error is correct, as you're looping through the fields in each row, your code is attempting to delete the row multiple times when the field doesn't match the filename. The deletion succeeds the first time, but fails on subsequent attempts.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your metadata.csv in the question?

Comment: @jrd1 I see. Are you suggesting that I should delete the rows outside the loop that iterates through the fields in the csv file?

Comment: @JazminCristina: Yeah; you can have a variable (e.g. `found`) that you'd use to track whether the filename is in the row's field - i.e. right below the `lines.append(row)` in your first edit. That could be set as a default as `False`, and set to `True` if the field's value is found in `lines`. Hence, after the loop through the row's fields you can check if `found` is True and delete the row from your `lines` variable, and reset found to `False`. A variation of that idea is to add the row only if the field is found based on the previous suggestion, which is effectively produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this block:

```py
for f in files:
    if field != f:
        lines.remove(row)
```

What that says is if the value of field is not equal to the value of f remove it. Well if files is a list of files unless the very first element in the list matches the value of fields it will be removed and the iteration will continue after that element has already been removed.

Instead I recommend making `files` as set and checking for membership in the set

```py
dir_path = Path('D:\audio_files')
    
csv_file_path = Path('D:\metadata.csv') 

lines = list()
files = set()

for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    f = f.strip('.wav')
    files.add(str(f))

with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file)
    for row in reader:
        lines.append(row)
        for field in row:
            if field not in files:
                lines.remove(row)
                continue
```

I would personally split those loops up and build the list of rows up then iterate over a copy removing elements but that may just by personal preference.

Comment: If multiple `fields` of the same `row` are not in `files`, this will throw the same error. I'd suggest adding a `continue` after `lines.remove(row)`

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers Totally right, fixed.

Comment: That is closer to what I am looking for, just not quite it. I tested the changes suggested and the same error keeps popping up. Perhaps I should delete the rows outside the for loops?